# jQuery .val('') does not clear text area input

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I want to clear the user input in a text area field, but it does not work.
When I print the value in the browser's console it appears to be "empty", but the text still exists in the field.

I am using Meteor 0.9.3. Here is my code:

```
Meteor.call('submitMessageForChat', message, this._id, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                throwWarning('error', error.reason, error.details);
                return null;
            }
            $('#chat-input').val('');
});

    <textarea id="chat-input" name="message" type="text" value="" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a demo..?

Comment: Can you confirm `$('#chat-input')` can be found from within the callback? Just `console.log()` it. While you're at the console: are there any errors logged by the browser?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, I can confirm that it can be found. I also can get the value (I need it because of the `submitMessageForChat` Meteor method call), I just can't set a new value.

Comment: Why are you using `type="text"` for `<textarea>`?

Comment: Also, do textareas have a value attribute?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I forgot one very important detail:
I am using [wysihtml5](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5).

`$('#chat-input').data("wysihtml5").editor.clear();` did the job.

[More info](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/issues/128).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
 $('#chat-input').html(''); but `val('');` should also work.
```

there is no tag `type="text"` for textarea.

you can use:

`$('textarea').val('');` also.